# Way to configure cowsay to output different colors for each host in ansible?

Tags: bash, colors, ansible, ascii

This is my ansible galaxy playbook:

```
- hosts: tag_Role_manager
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  roles:
    - some-role

- hosts: tag_Role_worker
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  roles:
    - some-role
```

As you can see, the hosts are executed sequentially. I have cowsay installed and I want for the cow to change color when it gets to the second host (tag_Role_worker) so that the output has better aesthetic .

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and to be honest I doubt that it will ever be implemented in core.

Your only chance is to write another callback plugin that does that.

Comment: Is it possible with some other program other than cowsay?

Comment: No. Mainly because the ANSI output captured will not be displayed as ANSI (colored).